# Entity lives in multiple aggregates in the same form

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

Context: Currently designing a product with a DDD mindset. Currently in a monolithic approach. However I'm refactoring a few things so I can change to a more loosely coupled monolith.

We have an entity called "Risk" (which is an abstract class with N subtypes). Currently have two aggregate roots who have a list of risks: **Contract** and **Damage**. This is demanded by the business logic, as when you create a damage from a specific risk in a contract, you need to take an exact copy of it at that given moment in time and add it to the damage.

However there's a new business rule that allows Customers (yet another aggregate root) to have a list of risks as well, without having any contract or damage (=> A prospect customer). The risk entity that would live under the Customer aggregate is an exact copy of the risks entity under contract & damage. The business itself is required to have the same data properties & behavior to the risk.

I'm not really a fan of sharing entities all over different aggregate roots, especially with the mindset of splitting it up to a more loosely coupled monolith. Plus the fact that the risk entity itself is an abstract with multiple subtypes.

Would a better approach be to make Risk an aggregate root as well and keep a reference ID to either a Customer, Contract or Damage?

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Would it be fair to consider a `Risk` a value object, rather than an entity? Does it have an identity and life cycle of its own (= entity), or is it represented purely by its contained values (= value object)? In other words, if both a customer and a contract have a "risk of ABC", is it important that they both refer to the _same_ risk, as opposed to two separate risks which (coincidentally) have the same values?

Comment: @Flater good point, someone else also suggested this. To be fair: I'm not sure. A risk also has multiple guarantees and guarantees have multiple deductibles (this is the business itself). Which means it isn't really a ValueObject right? A risk cannot exist without something, so upon creating you need to have a reference to either a Customer, Contract or Damage. A risk can and will be updated over time as well..

Comment: @Flater A risk can even change "owners" . Like you could add a risk to a potential customer without a contract.. but when he becomes an actual customer, the risk should move below the contract for that customer. (Talking on how the business works.)

Comment: Value objects do not have an upper limit on how much data they can contain. They are _conceptually_ different from entities. A very common example here is an `Address`. Your system may have several entities which all have an address, but that doesn't mean that these entities' addresses therefore have a unified lifecycle. For example, if you track both people and cars (and their registered addresses), just because I move house doesn't mean that this change of address also applies to the car. These addresses have different life cycles and just "happen" to contain the same values sometimes.

Comment: In short, none of the arguments you mention in the comments here are relevant to consider something a value object or not. Your interpretation of what a value object is or how it can/should be used is... misguided. I presume you may have misinterpreted (or have been misexplained) the conceptual purpose.

Comment: @Flater I use ValueObjects to avoid primitive obsession where necessary. Like on my Risks I have an Address, so I have a RiskAddress VO. But I also have, for example, a DrivingLicense VO on my Customer AR, which holds information about a specific driving license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you are building, it seems you've come to the natural conclusion that makes the most sense:

> Would a better approach be to make Risk an aggregate root as well and keep a reference ID to either a Customer, Contract or Damage?

Based on what you shared, it makes the most sense.

There are several cases where aggregates are associated with other aggregates, but the business logic surrounding it really suggests that it is it's own aggregate root.

For example. I have a system where we maintain metadata on a corpus of information, and users can make different types of requests against that corpus.  In this example, we'll call the corpus a "Collection", and the request types being "Information" or "Services".  All of the requests are children of the "Collection", but there are whole workflows around fulfilling those requests.

So in this almost contrived example, we have:

- Collection (1..n)

  - Request: Information (1..1)
  - Request: Service (1..1)

We found it worked better to have "Requests" and "Collections" be peers, and the "Request" was associated with a "Collection".

The requests have their own approval and fulfillment workflows independent of the collection's approval workflow.  We've gone to a full microservices architecture already, and this approach of promoting an aggregate element to be it's own root just made the whole design easier to comprehend.

Some of the clues that suggest something is a candidate to be promoted to it's own aggregate root and simply referenced by it's logical parent include:

- The customer talks about that thing independently of the parent.  (in your case risks)
- The same aggregate type can be associated with multiple types of parents.  (Contract, Damage, Customers)
- There are independent workflows/business logic surrounding the child and the parent

Those are just a few reasons, and there could be more rational reasons to promote something to be it's own aggregate root.  By doing this, you essentially decouple the concepts--but maintain the referential link you need.

Comment: Thanks! I like this approach. I'm not yet sure on how to solve it though as someone else pointed out it would maybe be better to create it as a ValueObject. But I'm not entirely sure on how that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few recommendations depending on the actual domain:

- Whether `Risk` should be an aggregate by itself, or part of the `Customer`, `Contract`, or `Damage` depends on whether it is an invariant in those aggregates. If the others cannot exist without a `Risk`, it makes sense to make `Risk` an entity of those aggregates.
- If `Risk` has its own lifecycle, entities, business logic and can change over time, it probably should be modeled as an Aggregate. In which case, it cannot be part of transactions of the other aggregates. The `Risk` aggregate must be created first and then referenced by others by its ID in their own transactions.
- If you want a snapshot of the Risk to be taken when other aggregates are created, you will have to create an entity under each of `Customer`, `Contract`, and `Damage`. The entity should be populated with data from the master `Risk` record during aggregate creation.
- There is a middle path between creating an independent copy of `Risk` across aggregates vs. referring to a Risk by its ID. You can create denormalized `Risk` records as entities under other aggregates (or even across different bounded contexts), which are updated by listening to Domain Events published by the `Risk` aggregate during its lifecycle.

Comment: A risk is an invariant in those aggregates, it's always the same. The others can perfectly exist without a risk. Risks have multiple entities below them as well (guarantees and guarantees can have deductibles => this is just how the business is). If the risk is linked to a customer, it should also be able to move under a contract.

Comment: About the snapshot of a risk. Why can't I just create a command (in a CQRS way) that copies the risks and creates a new one, but with a different link?

Comment: I think you are confused about what an Invariant is. An invariant is a business rule that can never be broken. It looks like the presence of Risk is not an invariant (a.k.a mandatory) if other aggregates can exist without it.

Comment: If Risk is an aggregate, I am assuming it changes over time. Will all the other aggregates get the update? If yes, you should store a reference to the Risk and not the Risk itself. If now, they are looking at an older version of the Risk,  so you have to create a copy (a snapshot) of the Risk within the aggregates.

Comment: Correct, risk is changing over time and risk isn't mandatory in other aggregates. I wasn't planning on storing the risk itself on the other aggregates, but only a reference ID. I looked to the business and it's like this: Customer has multiple risks, a risk can be referenced in multiple contracts. So if a risk needs to be referenced somewhere else, it needs to be an AR already since it isn't allowed to reference an entity under an AR.

Comment: The tricky part however is, that creating a damage (which can also reference multiple contracts), also contains risks, but in the damage aggregate it seems like the risk would be an entity or a VO rather than a reference to the risk aggregate. Since it would be a copy/snapshot of the risk. I wouldn't be mad to create a risk entity under damage if risk had only a few properties. But a risk has a load of properties, multiple subtypes via polymorphism + collections on it's own with even more polymorphism.

Comment: To clarify the last point, does the risk connected to damage change over time, or is it a snapshot captured at the time of damage aggregate creation?

Comment: The easy answer is: the risk under damage will change over time. 
The hard answer: there is no real business rule about this. It might change, it might not change. It most likely will change right after the damage occurred, but after a few weeks.. it probably will never be touched again. It works like this in the old application, if the damage it status is "closed" the risk shouldn't be changed anymore, but that's not a hard restriction. It's still possible to change it even the damage it's status is set to closed. Insurance business is .. weird.

Comment: I understand. I would go with the last option in my answer and preserve a copy of the Risk under Damage aggregate. You will listen to Risk change events and update the entity when you have to (based on one or more rules you just laid out).

Comment: That sounds like a nice solution indeed. However, if I'd break my monolith into pieces, I have this Risk object that is shared between different aggregate roots. Making the exact same Risk entity under every aggregate seems a bit silly since it's a 100% the same object every time, and always will be. The only thing that could affect it it it's aggregate root which could prevent one from changing the risk. Since Risk has 8 subtypes, it would be a lot of work if I gave every aggregate it's own definition of risk which is exactly the same in the other ARs.

Comment: I am confused. You don't want to refer to the Risk aggregate by its ID, to avoid duplication. You say that different aggregates treat the same risk object differently based on complex business rules. You also don't want to create copies. What solution are you leaning towards? BTW, you are introducing accidental complexity by sharing the same Risk aggregate across different concepts, if they treat Risk differently. That is how changes cause ripple effects across the system and result in regressions.

Comment: As said in my first comment, risk isn't treated differently. It's always the same set of data properties and behavior. It doesn't have strict business rules. I haven't found an ideal solution yet since there's always one big drawback to work with. Right now I'm checking out if I maybe rather use composition over inheritance for the risks to make the domain object more workable. After that I will re-evaluate this question with new insights.